# Dropwizard quartz jobs won't work with Guicey

Tags: java, java-8, quartz-scheduler, guice, dropwizard

I'm using dropwizard 1.0.5, dropwizard-guicey 4.0.1 (https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey), spinscale quartz implementation 3.0.0 (https://github.com/spinscale/dropwizard-jobs).

I want to be able to inject my dependencies into the job instances that quartz/spinscale creates. To do this, I tried to load in the following library https://github.com/spinscale/dropwizard-jobs/tree/master/dropwizard-jobs-guice

The problem with this is, when the Guice dropwizard jobs bundle is created, the Guice injector is not yet initialized, so I get an NPE.

Example:
`MyApplication.java`

```
  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyConfiguration> bootstrap) {

    // Initialize Guice for dependency injection

    GuiceBundle guiceBundle = GuiceBundle.builder()
            .bindConfigurationInterfaces()
            .enableAutoConfig(getClass().getPackage().getName())
            .modules(new MyModule(bootstrap.getMetricRegistry()))
            .build();
    bootstrap.addBundle(guiceBundle);

    bootstrap.addBundle(new GuiceJobsBundle(guiceBundle.getInjector()));
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Guice not initialized
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:226)
```

To fix this, I tried creating my own version of the `GuiceJobsBundle` that takes in the `GuiceBundle` and doesn't set the injector until `bundle.run()` is called. But still, I get an NPE.

`MyApplication`

```
  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    // Substitute environment variable references in the configuration file
    bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(new SubstitutingSourceProvider(
        bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(),
        new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(false, true)
    ));

    // Initialize Guice for dependency injection

    GuiceBundle guiceBundle = GuiceBundle.builder()
            .bindConfigurationInterfaces()
            .enableAutoConfig(getClass().getPackage().getName())
            .modules(new MyModule(bootstrap.getMetricRegistry()))
            .build();
    bootstrap.addBundle(guiceBundle);

    bootstrap.addBundle(new GuiceyJobsBundle(guiceBundle));
  }
```

`GuiceyJobsBundle`

```
public class GuiceyJobsBundle extends JobsBundle {

    private GuiceBundle guiceBundle;

    public GuiceyJobsBundle(GuiceBundle guiceBundle) {
        this.guiceBundle = guiceBundle;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Environment environment) {
        JobManager jobManager = new GuiceJobManager(guiceBundle.getInjector());
        environment.lifecycle().manage(jobManager);
    }
}
```

When is a bundle's `run()` method called? And has anybody found a working solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost right about the last fix, you just forget to bind configuration `jobManager.configure(configuration)` (that's why NPE was thrown).

But you can do integration without bundles at all. I see you already use classpath scan, so just drop these extensions somewhere:

```
@Singleton
public class JobsManager extends GuiceJobManager {

    @Inject
    public JobsManager(Injector injector, JobsAppConfiguration configuration) {
        super(injector);
        configure(configuration);
    }
}
```

This will be recognized as Manged bean and will start/stop quartz context. Internally it searches for jobs in registered guice bindngs (using dropwizard-jobs logic).

```
public class JobsInstaller implements FeatureInstaller<Job>, TypeInstaller<Job> {

    private final Reporter reporter = new Reporter(JobsInstaller.class, "jobs =");

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Class<?> type) {
        return FeatureUtils.is(type, Job.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void install(Environment environment, Class<Job> type) {
        // here we can also look for class annotations and show more info in console
        // (omitted for simplicity)
        reporter.line("(%s)", type.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void report() {
        reporter.report();
    }
}
```

This installer simply binds all jobs to guice context so `JobsManager` could install them (just to avoid manual jobs binding).

I add compete example to guicey-examples repo: https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey-examples/tree/master/dropwizard-jobs

Comment: this works great. However, can you explain what the `JobsInstaller` does a little more? Is `bootstrap.addBundle(new JobsBundle(jobInstance));` an example of the manual binding you are referring to? How does it do this? From what I have read about installers, all it does is bind it to guice (i.e: `bind(SampleJob.class).in(Singleton)`). I don't understand how doing this makes it so I don't need to register job to jobs bundle. Can you explain how this works a little more?

Comment: Original dropwizard-jobs bundle manually registers managed object (GuiceJobManager) to start/stop quartz and [search in all registered guice bindings](https://github.com/spinscale/dropwizard-jobs/blob/master/dropwizard-jobs-guice/src/main/java/de/spinscale/dropwizard/jobs/GuiceJobManager.java#L24) job beans to register them.  So each task must be bound in guice module in order to be registered in quartz. These bindings I call "manual" because you have to manually register all job beans in guice module.

Comment: With guicey we don't need bundle as our managed bean (JobsManager) could be installed automatically by classpath scan. But we still need to manually bound all jobs in guice context so they could be found in guice context. To avoid this manual step we use installer which will find all job classes during classpath scan and implicitly bound them to guice context (so dropwizard-jobs could "see" them). Also, installer prints all used jobs, which could be very helpful in some cases.